# System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In View I am Getting Error

This is My Controller

```
using (var db=new wipoeeshetronEntities())
        {
            ViewBag.Role = new SelectList(db.masterroledet_tbl.Where(m => m.IsDeleted == 0), "RoleID", "RoleName");
            var RoleplayModule = db.masterrolemodulelink_tbl.Where(e => e.IsDeleted == 0);
            return View(RoleplayModule.ToList());  
        }
```

This is My  View

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleId1", (SelectList)ViewData["Role"], "--Select Role for Update--", new { @id = "RoleID1", @class = "btn btn-block orange dropdown-toggle ", @name = "RoleID1", @style = "width:20%;display:inline;float:right", @required = "required" })
```

Comment: Please learn how to format your questions.

Comment: You are passing ViewBag and accepting (SelectList)ViewData["Role"] its should be ViewBag.Role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ToList inside SelectList also

```
ViewBag.Role = new SelectList(db.masterroledet_tbl.Where(m => m.IsDeleted == 0).ToList(), "RoleID", "RoleName");
```

The problem is that you pass the view unexecuted query, when view tries to execute the context is already disposed in using

Comment: well explained.